# Number of truth tables for a 2 letter formula

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am reading a book called "The Haskell Road to Logic, Maths and Programming"

A question in the book is:
"How many truth tables are there for 2-letter formula's"

The answer in the answer sheet is:
"A two-letter formula has a truth table with four rows. The value at every row can be either t of f, so there
are `2^4 = 16` truth tables altogether."

Now I don't understand, how a 2 letter formula, can have 16 truth tables?
Let's say `P ⇒ Q`
It will look like:

```
P    Q    (P⇒Q)
T    T    T
T    F    F
F    T    T
F    F    T
```

Now how can this have 16 tables? It looks like one table to me.

Comment: Their explanation rightfully (but unjustifiably) assumes that every truth table with four rows is attainable from a two letter formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For different formulae, the third column above can have different 4-tuples of T or F. So there are $2^4$ different formulae. For example, $P\wedge Q$,

$$\begin{array}{cc|c}
P&Q&P\wedge Q\\\hline
T&T&T\\
T&F&F\\
F&T&F\\
F&F&F
\end{array}$$

is another truth table with a different 4-tuple $(T,F,F,F)$.

In fact, for any integer $0\le n\le 2^4-1$, let $b_i\in\{0,1\}$ be the $i$th bit of $n$ ($i = 0,1,2,3$), then $f_n$ is a new function defined by

$$\begin{array}{cc|c}
P&Q&f_n(P,Q)\\\hline
0&0&b_0\\
0&1&b_1\\
1&0&b_2\\
1&1&b_3
\end{array}$$

Comment: Thank you for answering, I get it now :)

Answer (score 3):

What they are asking is how many possible relationships like this are there. You have 4 rows, first 2 columns are fixed, last column has 4 entries with T/F each, so $2^4=16$ total choices.